# How can I send a message without a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to send a message without command if a condition is true. I wrote this code but it doesn't send any message.

```py
from discord import channel
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
token = '***'
condition = True

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('crypto-bot è pronto')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content == '.ciao':
        await message.channel.send('ciao')

async def my_background_task():
    if condition == True:
        channel = bot.get_channel(926067178539712512)
        await channel.send('true')

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Is it the `on_ready()` function giving you problems? Does it print in your terminal?

Comment: yes, it prints in the terminal. I think the problem is my_background_task. En fact it doesn't print true in the discord channel

Comment: There is nothing triggering the `my_background_task` function. You have to bind it to an event. Right now, the function exists but nothing is calling it. It's only once the function is called that the `condition` is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def my_background_task():
    if condition == True:
        channel = bot.get_channel(926067178539712512)
        await channel.send('true')

await my_background_task()
```

I know  for sure it wasnt working because you didnt trigger the function..but I dont know if this will work or not if this doesnt work trigger the function    in the on_message function like this

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content == '.ciao':
        await message.channel.send('ciao')
    await my_background_task()
```

Comment: The second code will work, but the downside is that it will send `true` only when someone triggers the `on_message` event by sending a message on server.

Comment: @RiveN you are right maybe your answer will work but we need to know what The_Hacker wants todo

Comment: [@l---Wernia---l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17664646/l-wernia-l) you're right. Your answer might be better than mine if [@The_Hacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17319247/the-hacker) would like to trigger the function with a message.

Comment: yea @RiveN if im not wrong your answer just sends 'true' every 5 seconds right?? that could cause issues

Comment: Yes, that's right. That's how I understood @The_Hacker's question. I'll edit my answer and add additional solution if you want to avoid it. Good point :)

Comment: btw @RiveN you just helped me figure smthing that i was going to add in my bot thankss!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop) for this. It will run every "x" seconds (in my example it's 5 seconds, but you can change it to `minutes` or `hours`).

```py
from discord.ext import tasks # add this import

condition = True

@tasks.loop(seconds=5) # choose how often you want to run this function (e.g every 5 seconds)
async def my_background_task():
    if condition == True:
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(926067178539712512)
        await channel.send('true')

my_background_task.start() # put this before `bot.run(token)`
```

---

Like [@l---Wernia---l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17664646) noticed it will continue sending the message until the condition changes. If you want to send only one message then you have to change the `condition` to `False`.

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def my_background_task():
    global condition # if you want to change global variable inside the function you have to add this line
    if condition == True:
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(926067178539712512)
        await channel.send('true')

        condition = False # changing condition at the end
```